# Fetch data regarding the total visits and revenue from customers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, tbl_customers and tbl_transactions, where the fields of them are as follows:

```
**tbl_customer:**

c_id  |  c_name  |  age  |  Slab  |  gender  |  occupation  |  married  |  priority  |  ratings  |  contact  |  email  |  dob  |  anniversary

**tbl_transaction**


t_id  |  c_id  |  d_id  |  f_id  |  date_time  |  bill  |  member
```

The table **tbl_transaction** is a global table containing the transactions of all departments, differentiated by **d_id**.

Now I want to run a query that fetches **c_id**, **total visits**(means no of rows a c_id apppears in tbl_transaction), **total revenue**(means SUM(bill) of a particular c_id in) and the respective priority and ratings as it is in tbl_customer.

The query I was trying is :

```
Select c_id,
COUNT(cid) as tot_visit,
SUM(bill) as tot_revenue, priority, ratings 
From tbl_customer c
inner join tbl_transaction t on c.c_id=t.c_id
Where $r_id='r1' AND $c_id='".$cid."'
group by c_id
```

So basicaly I want to display the total visits and revenue of each customer in customer table, but not sure what is the right way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: This is the error I am getting in SQL Engine]
This is the error I am getting in SQL Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error there are fields in both tables that have same name in your tables you need to give the table alias for the field, also when you are filtering on only one group then there is no need to use group by because you are using `AND c.c_id='".$cid."'` for a single group

```
Select c.c_id,
COUNT(c.cid) as tot_visit,
SUM(t.bill) as tot_revenue, c.priority, c.ratings 
From tbl_customer c
inner join tbl_transaction t on c.c_id=t.c_id
Where $r_id='r1' AND c.c_id='".$cid."'
group by c.c_id
```

Comment: thnks..that worked...but this is working when i am passing r_id and c_id manualy... like this:

SELECT c.c_id, COUNT( c.c_id ) AS tot_visit, SUM( t.bill ) AS tot_revenue, c.priority, c.ratings
FROM tbl_customer c
INNER JOIN tbl_transaction t ON c.c_id = t.c_id
WHERE t.r_id =  'r1'
AND c.c_id =  '1'
GROUP BY c.c_id

What should I do to fetch data of all customers??

Comment: To fetch data for all customer then remove `AND c.c_id = '1'` filter

Answer (score 0):

In general the query is fine. I would replace inner join with outer to process customers cho don't have transactions

```
Select c_id, COUNT(cid) as tot_visit, SUM(bill) as tot_revenue, 
       priority, ratings 
From tbl_customer c LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction t on c.c_id=t.c_id 
Where $r_id='r1' AND $c_id='".$cid."' 
group by c_id
```

Comment: `c_id` is the customer id so and also in `WHERE` clause so there is no means of using LEFT join there will be a single resultant row because he using the `GROUP BY` on `c_id`